# TabControl- preventing user from changing the selected tab: MessageBox causing bug

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, tabcontrol

I've been pounding away at this issue for a little while, and have only found part of the solution.

I'm trying to set up a TabControl so that I can in some cases prevent the user from changing the currently selected tab. When the user is prevented from changing the currently selected tab, then they are shown a dialog box.

I have already read the following documents:

- [WPF - reset ListBox scroll position when ItemsSource changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793030/wpf-reset-listbox-scroll-position-when-itemssource-changes)
- http://wizardsofsmart.net/uncategorized/itemssourcechanged-event-using-attached-dependency-properties/
- http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/how-to-prevent-a-tabitem-from-being-selected/
- http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f7b46018-1e97-4bbe-ada8-49b75dbc1da2/

I have implemented the solution indicated in the 3rd link (though all of the above create the same error seen below).  And it works, **but**...

Things mess up thoroughly if the user does the following:

- attempts to change the tab when such an action is disallowed.  The MessageBox pops up with the error.
- the user clicks "OK" and is returned to the original window.
- the user tries again to change the tab.  **No MessageBox appears.**
- if the user minimizes the window, and then maximizes it again, then the MessageBox that was supposed to appear earlier appears.
- the user clicks "OK" and is returned to the original window... **but the tab has been changed to the one they selected before, even though they should not be able to change tabs**.

This is obviously **not** ideal behavior.  **Why isn't the MessageBox appearing the second time, and why is the tab changing when it should be disallowed from doing so?**

If I remove the MessageBox part, it works fine.

Here is the code for the TabControl.SelectionChanged event handler:

```
bool _isChanging = false;

    private void tabControlForNavigation_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isChanging && canChangeTabs.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
            _isChanging = true;


            bool canLeave = canChangeTabs.IsChecked.Value;  //normally this would be replaced by a check in the ViewModel

            if (!canLeave)
            {
                int prevIndex = tabControlForNavigation.Items.IndexOf(tabControlForNavigation.SelectedContent);
                tabControlForNavigation.SelectedIndex = prevIndex;
                MessageBox.Show("Can't change tabs!"); //if I comment out this line, everything works fine.
            }

            _isChanging = false;
        }
    }
```

I am using MVVM to implement this.  The Window looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestTabControlSwitching.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox x:Name="canChangeTabs"
              Content="Can Change Tabs"
              IsChecked="True" />
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControlForNavigation"
                Grid.Row="1"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                SelectionChanged="tabControlForNavigation_SelectionChanged"
                Margin="4"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I'm omitting the rest of the code for sake of brevity- there is a pretty straight-forward ViewModel structure backing the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, the problem is the `MessageBox` inside the event handler. The focus will change to the `MessageBox` and you can get all kind of undesired effects. I've had my own problems with this.

Here is a couple of SO question on the same subject
[WPF: Does MessageBox Break PreviewMouseDown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546388/wpf-does-messagebox-break-previewmousedown)
[Wpf stop routing event when MessageBox appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556422/wpf-stop-routing-event-when-messagebox-appear)

If you must display a message to the user then an alternate approach might be to create a new `Window` which you style like a `MessageBox` and then call `Show` (**not** `ShowDialog`) on it inside the event handler.

Comment: Do we know if this is a bug in WPF?  Or is it for some strange reason "by design"?

Comment: I'm not sure, searched for the reason for this myself a couple of years back but never found any info. Just looked at it with Reflector but it's to complex to tell what's going on..

Comment: <sigh/>  Oh well. Your work-around is non-ideal, but doable.  Unfortunately I need to have some sort of pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but I have a very easy way to accomplish this:

Use the `tab_Enter` event and create a method that performs your check and displays a `MessageBox` to the user and then set `myTabs.SelectedIndex` to the prior index. A simple example:

```
    private void someTab_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myCondition)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, myCondition will not let you move to this tab.");
            myTabs.SelectedIndex = someOtherTabIndex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a very detailed question. I had the same problem you had (i.e. the message box doesn't display on 2nd or 3rd selection changed until you minimize and maximize the window) and after much debugging and multiple google searches, stumbled on the below linked MSDN forum post.

[[TabControl SelectionChanged Strange Behaviour?]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bf500ad-0f6f-4a89-8d03-92e03daa2ae8/tabcontrol-selectionchanged-strange-behaviour?forum=wpf)

Please ignore the poorly formatted question and answer. But as mentioned in the answer, putting it inside a dispatcher and focussing the selected tab after setting the index resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an easy trick. Just make focusable=False for the Tab header.

```
<TabItem Header="MY TAB" Focusable="False">
```

You could bind this property to your view model.

```
<TabItem Header="MY TAB" Focusable="{Binding Bool_CanHasCheeseBurger}">
```